# how to update single data from a single column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am inserting the cars using check boxes. i want to remove Audi car from the list . how can i achieve this one

```
+----+------------+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| id | sms        | Cars            | usertype | noprice | regdate    | time     |
+----+------------+----------+----------+---------+------------+----------+------
| 82 | hello boys | BMW Audi Maruti |  Driver  | 50      | 2014-08-24 | 09:11:50 |
+----+------------+-----------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Expected result

```
+----+------------+------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| id | sms        |   Cars     | usertype | noprice | regdate    | time     |
+----+------------+----------+----------+---------+------------+----------+--
| 82 | hello boys | BMW Maruti | Driver    | 50      | 2014-08-24 | 09:11:50|
+----+------------+------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()` function to update your column

```
update table set cars = replace(cars ,'Audi','') where id = 82
```

[*Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56a20/1)

Or its better to relate cars with single user in a separate table with car name and associated user id ,each car and user relation in a separate row